# Are C++ constructors called pre-initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose we declare `A` to be of type `Type`:

```
Type A;
```

**Question:** is the `Type` constructor for `A` called at this point? Or is it only after we initialize `A` that a constructor is called?

Comment: `initialization` literally means `allocate memory and call Type's constructor`.

Comment: In what context is the declaration that you are talking about? Is it inside a class? Is it inside a function? Is it inside some file outside of any functions?

Comment: Maybe. If `Type A;` is in the definition of another class or structure, it won't be.

Comment: C++ is not Ruby (where anything is an object)

Comment: The constructor *is* the initialization.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It's of no consequence to the question.

Comment: @PreferenceBean Obviously, I disagree with this assertion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'm sorry to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

> is the Type constructor for A called at this point? Or is it only after we initialize A that a constructor is called?

You *are* initializing `A` here, whether you explicitly provided a value for that process or not.

There is no opportunity to initialise `A` "later"; you can only assign to it later. (Early C texts talk about "initialising" numeric values long after declaration, but that's a different language, a different century, and a different set of descriptive idioms.)

So, yes, the constructor is called as soon as the object's lifetime begins. That's either right there and then, on that line, or if a class member then of course it's when the encapsulating class is being initialised and it's this member's turn.

Of course you could have proven this with a simple `std::cout` pair.

Comment: not if `Type A;` is a class member declaration.  We need to know where this is to provide a valid answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I concede that "right there and then" is ambiguous, but that's the case no matter what the context, especially given the as-if rule. Pedanticism aside, I'm satisfied that this answer fully and completely validly addresses the factors the OP is asking about. The only relevant point is the OP's confusion over what initialisation means and whether constructor calls can ever be delayed past the beginning of an object's lifetime.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I've addressed the ambiguity anyway so there should be no room for error now.

Comment: Well I still think there is but whatever.  The Q is closed now.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It shouldn't be. The question is perfectly clear. Seems like you're just looking for reasons to be negative here :(

Comment: Its not clear to me at all and 4 other people agreed.  We have no idea where `Type A;` is so we cannot say what is going to happen.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It doesn't matter where `Type A` is so we can indeed say what's going to happen, within the scope of what is being asked. Indeed, that's precisely what I've done! Note that 50 visitors did _not_ agree with you. Anyway, we'll see whether it gets re-opened or not but either way I'm happy with my answer. Cheers

Comment: 50 people cant vote to close so we will never know.  There could have been many more flags but we will never know.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Even if there were, it still wouldn't automatically make you right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called immediately.  When you assign it a value, the assignment operator is called instead.

The only exception is this:

```
Type a = value;
```

Here some compiler with some settings may relax it and call constructor directly with the value as parameter. But it still needs to be part of declaration.

Comment: not if `Type A;` is a class member declaration.

Comment: Also, what if `Type A;` is a global deceleration.

Comment: @Ben autoreplacing spelling checkers bring me such joy.

Comment: @NathanOliver : In that case it's called as part of parent constructor but the concept is pretty much the same as the instantion is part of parent instantion.

Comment: @user4581301 ahahahaha, declaration.

Comment: But if `Type A;` is a class member declaration then it is not called immediately and your answer is wrong.  We need context from the OP to be able to answer this.

Comment: @NathanOliver : technically the instance member declaration or rather its construction becomes a part of parent constructor. They're initialized in the same order as they appear in the code and by default empty constructor is called unless specified otherwise in member initialization.

Comment: Yes but nothing is constructed until the parent class is constructed.  This is different than your answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver : well, of course because it doesn't exist yet. But then this row wasn't executed yet, it only passed the compilation time. This is still consistent with global or local variables and not in conflict with the answe I believe.